# yii2 confirm and/or choice in the middle of transction

Tags: transactions, yii2, confirm

I'm creating a lot of different, related models in batch, with the help of uploaded files. Is there a way, to make the whole process like a conversation with the user, but keeping it in a try-catch transactional environment? I mean, for example in the middle of the process there is a point when there are two possibilities to choose from, and the user would be able to choose one, or an "are you sure you want to that?" and so on, and then the process would go further?

Comment: Do you mind sharing more details about what you main task is? I mean more background to "I'm creating a lot of different, related models in batch, with the help of uploaded files". Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know how could I explain it better. I mean it as I said. I'm uploading files, and extract informations from them, and I assign these informations manually to model attributes. I know it's not really a yii way, but I have to do so. We have text files, or csvs, about hotels, and visitors. The user is loading this csv/text up, and the function extracts it creates a model for the Hotel, with all necessary attributes assigned, validates, saves, then comes models for Visitor(s) in a for-each loop. And for example, nationality is not yet in the database,

Comment: or the attribute (text) is not clearly defined, and you can choose from two possibilities. And it's simply awkward to roll the whole transaction back only because of such a "small" question. And I was wondering if it would be possible to show a form in the middle of the transaction process where the user could choose one.

Comment: Ah now I get it...I was not sure if you are creating models or model-instances in batch-fashion ;)!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, model-instances! :)

Comment: Did you see the answer? Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah I've seen it, but I need a little bit more time to think it through how can I include this in my workflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of would be the following.

**Import-Table as an intermediate storage**

1. When importing read your files into an "import"-table. One record for each line of your csv- or text-file. Save the whole line as it was read.
2. Before saving it, assert that no identical line was saved before (unique index?)
3. Then in another controller action which gets called after the upload iterate over all the entries in this table. Process the data and save it immediately or ask the user when necessary.
4. Either remove the line from the import-table or mark it as imported. The later has the advantage that you can track already imported lines but needs some cleanup after a certain interval to prevent data-bloating.
5. done!

**Table structure**

Just as an example...here is the create statement you could use for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `import` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `is_imported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's even more easy and I'm going to to do so, I'm going to send all data to a new form (with additional possible attributes to choose from), where the user can choose one or more additional informations needed to run the transaction problemfree.